# $_POST to $_SESSION Issues

Tags: php, redirect, post, get

I'm having trouble getting a much larger function to post form details in browsers other than chrome. I've narrowed my problem down to my post, redirect, get section of code.

I have recreated the problem with this small function that contains a form and my PRG statement:

```
function testForm(){

    session_start();
    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1);

    if(count($_POST) > 0) {
        $_SESSION['testFormText'] = $_POST['testFormText'];

            if(isset($_POST['testSubmit'])){
        $_SESSION['testSubmit'] = 1;}

        header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
        header("Location: https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/test-form/");
        die();
    }
    elseif (isset($_SESSION['testFormText'])){
        $text = $_SESSION['testFormText'];

        $submit = $_SESSION['testSubmit'];

        /*
            Put database-affecting code here.
        */


        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
    }else{
        $text = null;   

    }


    echo '<div class="testForm">
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="text" name="testFormText"/>
            <input type="submit" name="testSubmit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
    ';  


    echo $text;
}
```

The function works correctly in chrome. Enter something into the input and submit the form. The data is sent to `$_POST` then set as a session variable. If the session is set, it is then echoed as the variable $text after the page is redirected back to itself from submitting the form.

This however does not work with firefox and safari. If anyone can suggest how to correctly set the `$_POST` as a session it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have tested your code and it is working fine for me in Firefox. Can you remove https part and test again. Its a guss only that might be https in local system of yours is not recognized in Firefox.

Comment: @joyd I changed https to http and it's still producing the same results.

Comment: well I am short of suggestions now :( ... This code works perfectly for me !

Comment: @joyd thanks for taking the time to check it out. I really hope it doesn't have anything to do w/ the way my server is set bc I know bluehost won't bat an eye